# How to print a key from a dictionary, if the value is given

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my dictionary with words and definitions:

```
Vocab={'Precaution' : "a measure taken in advance to avert possible evil or to secure good results",
'Cautious' : "showing, using, or characterized by caution",
'Cautionary' : "of the nature of or containing a warning",
'Dissuade' : "to deter by advice or persuasion; persuade not to do something",
'Persuasion' : "the act of persuading or seeking to persuade"}
```

Here is another dictionary, However, this dictionary contains Latin roots as keys and vocab as values.

```
 Roots={'Caut' :{'Precaution', 'Catious', 'Cautionary'}, 'Saud' :{'Dissuade', 'Persuasion'}}
```

Now this is a small quiz game:

```
print "If you want to know the root of the word, type 'root'"
while 1:
    y = random.choice(Vocab.keys())
    print y
    t2=raw_input("What is the definition?: ")
    if t2 in Vocab[y]:
        print 'All those words were in the definition!'
        print Vocab[y]
    elif t2 not in Vocab[y]:
        if t2 == 'root':
            print Roots
        elif t2 != 'root':
            for key,y in Roots.iteritems()):
                print key
```

I want the user to input 'root', and then have the root pop up as a hint. After the root pops up, the same question word will be on the screen for him to try and answer. When the user inputs 'root', the whole dictionary comes up. How do I get it to print out the root that the word is pat of?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem with what you have? Have you considered creating a reversed dictionary to make the lookup easier?

Comment: @jonsrsharpe I want the key of the randomly chosen value to be shown when the user inputs 'root'.

Comment: Yes, I understand that; my question really is *"what, if any, effort have you put into achieving that yourself?"*

Comment: @jonsrsharpe I've been looking for the answer since yesterday. I can't find anything. I've tried other methods, and I know i can just create a reversed dictionary. I want to know if there is a shorter way. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), then; just write up your working code with the reversed dictionary, correct the other errors, and post it there to see if anyone can suggest any improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion 1: Find the key-value pair for which the input word is in the values, then print the key.

```
if t2 == 'root':
    for root,words in Roots.iteritems():
        if y in words:
            print root
            break
```

Suggestion 2: create this dictionary

```
invRoots = {word:root for root,words in Roots.iteritems() for word in words}
```

and use

```
if t2 == 'root':
    print invRoots[y]
```

Another thing: your `Roots` contain a typo: `'Catious'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I understand what you need, but why not store the roots directly with the main vocabulary words, in one data structure? That will make it easy to print the root for the current word, without the need for any reversed-dictionaries or other lookup strategies.

```
vocab = {
    'Precaution' : {'root': 'Caut', 'def': 'definition': 'a measure ...'},
    'Cautious'   : {'root': 'Caut', 'def': 'showing, using, ...'},
    'Dissuade'   : {'root': 'Saud', 'def': 'to deter ...'},
}
```

That approach is also consistent with an O-O design, should your problem need to evolve in that direction in the future, where every `Word` instance would contain its relevant attributes: definition, root, alternative spellings, etc.

For example:

```
wroots = { w : r for r, ws in Roots.iteritems() for w in ws }
vocab  = { w : dict(root = wroots[w], defin = d) for w, d in Vocab.iteritems() }
```

Comment: This would work, but it would take a lot of time. I have about 150 words.

Comment: +1 I like your approach!

Comment: @user2757442 Time? Just write code to build the merged data (see edited answer).